# map with constant value fails in simple closure

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, closures

Given the following Swift code:

```
[1,2,3].map{1}
```

I am getting a `Could not find member map`. I realize this is somewhat contrived, but I would have thought it should still work? Has anybody run across a reason why this fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use shorthand argument names in the closure, then you can omit the parameter list (see page 261):

> Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline
>   closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure’s
>   arguments by the names `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, and so on.
>
> If you use these shorthand argument names within your closure
>   expression, you can omit the closure’s argument list from its
>   definition, and the number and type of the shorthand argument names
>   will be inferred from the expected function type.

Comment: Page 261 is about initializers

Comment: hmm strange ibooks. the section is titled "Shorthand Argument Names"

Comment: Ah, I see. It's page *161*.

Comment: That is some subtle wording. Thanks!